# Time conversion to hours and minutes with am and pm

Tags: php

Currently, I have data as below. But, it wasn't a timestamp value. It was a time itself

```
$start_time = '150630';
$end_time = '180630';
```

I want to change the format like  `03:06 PM – 06:06 PM` i tried

```
$init = 150630;
$hours = floor($init / 3600);
$minutes = floor(($init / 60) % 60);
$seconds = $init % 60;

echo "$hours:$minutes:$seconds";
```

But the format and value is not as expected.
Please help me how to solve this

Comment: i think you don't even understand your start_time end_time format

Comment: @Kasnady-sorry if i made anything wrong.please correct me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You doesn't need time converter as your string wasn't a valid timestamp. Instead, it was time itself. You just need to extract the `hour`, `min`, and `second`.

Refer below

```
<?php

$start_time = "150630";

$hours = substr($start_time, 0, 2); // this is actual hours
$mins = substr($start_time, 2, 2); // this is actual minutes
$secs = substr($start_time, 4, 2); // this is actual seconds    

if ($hours < 12) {
    $actTime = "$hours:$mins:$secs AM";
} else {
    $actTime = ($hours-12).":$mins:$secs PM";
}

echo $actTime; // this is the time format you want
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..thanks dear it's also working.perfect

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_split` function as your time format is not timestamp.

It will extract `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds`.

check the below code :

```
<?php
$start_time = '150630';
$end_time = '180630';

$startTimeA = str_split($start_time, 2);
$endTimeA = str_split($end_time, 2);

$startTime = "";
$AmOrPm = "AM";
if ($startTimeA[0] > 12) {
    $startTime .= (int) ($startTimeA[0] - 12);
    $AmOrPm = "PM";
}
echo $startTime .= ":" . $startTimeA[1] . " " . $AmOrPm;


$endTime = "";
$AmOrPm = "AM";
if ($endTimeA[0] > 12) {
    $endTime .= (int) ($endTimeA[0] - 12);
    $AmOrPm = "PM";
}
echo $endTime .= ":" . $endTimeA[1] . " " . $AmOrPm;

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Php Date [Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) And [Strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp.
And Convert It like

```
echo $start_time = date('h:i:a' , strtotime(150630));
//o/p 03:06:pm
```

Comment: i Updated Answer

Comment: its my pleasure .

Comment: @traker are you sure the result is as what you expected?

Comment: @RahulShrivastava me.. i'm down voting it caused the result as not as expected from the question

Comment: Its not giving correct out put when the time is `00:30:00 AM`, check https://eval.in/960613 it gives `03:36:00 pm`

Comment: Because Your Timestamp is  003000  @ravisachaniya. And also Questioner is not cleared about this So `strtotime()` is useful in all condition.

Comment: @TarangP yes correct but OP has time in format `HHmmss`